# Problem with wrapping long titles on my Careers 2.0 profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On my Careers 2.0 [profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/kencenerelli) I have a very long title under Education. A portion of this title is overlapping the years I attended. The rest of the title does get pushed to the second line.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Reproduced in FF14.

Comment: Thanks, we made a bunch of CSS changes yesterday. We’ll get a fix in place ASAP.

Comment: Thanks Matt - I will watch for the fix!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [Matt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147667/matt-sherman) fixed this bug.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks Matt for fixing this!